# Is there any synthetic spectrum software for neutron star?

Tags: neutron-star, spectra, software, stellar-atmospheres

Is there any software that can calculate the emergent spectrum of a neutron star photosphere, for Teff is about 1e7K, density is above 1e21-1e22 cm^-3 ? Output line wavelength is about 0-100A is enough. Can calculate Fe and heavier metal isotope like Ni. Since the dense and temperature is high, many softwares seem do not suitable.

Comment: "...about 0-100A is enough." Technically speaking, a spectrum that stars at 0 angstroms is *infinite!* Is it possible to express the upper energy limit in MeV or GeV rather than using a wavelength?

Comment: At $10^7$ K, a blackbody spectrum is not going to be too far wrong. How detailed do you need it to be and what do you know about the photospheric composition of your neutron star?

Comment: The reason to use A instead of MeV or GeV is i want to compare the spectra with the soft X-ray observation band, they are in KeV in energy or A in wavelength, so both of them is OK. And i want to see the line emission and absorption under different abundance, such as different H, He, C,N,O,Fe and other heavier isotropes. Under what temperature, density... will have what kind of ionizaiton component.

Comment: This paper publishes model spectra. Not much sign of emission or absorption lines. https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015A%26A...581A..83N/abstract  BTW, your numbers for the density of a neutron star photosphere are very odd. The mass density would be around $10^6$ g/cc, so the number densities would be of order $10^{32}$ /cc.

Comment: Thank you @Rob, the result of that paper do not contain much spectra, but i can go to see whether their software can produce the lines i'm seeking for. Thank you.